# Alternative for sleep in a zsh sub shell inner loop

Tags: command-line-interface, posix, zsh, sleep, curses

I use zsh (zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)) and zsh/curses for a small command line interface. The content of the view should automatically adjust when the window size changes. I tried a solution with trap SIGWINCH, but with zsh (I tried it on Ubuntu and macOS) trap SIGWINCH obviously doesn't work. So I use a background shell with a busy loop (see `monitorwindowsize` below) that sends SIGUSR1 to the parent shell to signal it to resize the window. The only solution I've found to make the inner loop wait a while is to call `sleep` (e.g. call `read -t 10` does not work here), but - you know - sleep creates a new process each time it's called. And of course I want to call the resize function as fast as possible, so I'm interested in keeping the sleep time as short as possible, i.e. calling sleep quite often. So my question is if there is an alternative for sleep under zsh that works in a sub-shell. Or is there a better solution than using the busy loop with this zsh/curses code.

The code:

```
#!/bin/zsh

zmodload zsh/curses

loop ()
{
    monitorwindowsize $1 &
    view
    while true; do
        read -t 1000
    done
}

view ()
{
    zcurses addwin mywin $(( LINES-4 )) $(( COLUMNS-4 )) 2 2 
    zcurses clear mywin
    zcurses border mywin
    zcurses refresh mywin
    zcurses move mywin $(( (LINES-4)/2 )) $(( (COLUMNS-8)/2 ))
    zcurses string mywin "Box"
    zcurses refresh mywin
}

resetview ()
{
    zcurses end
    tput clear
    zcurses clear mywin
    zcurses refresh mywin
    zcurses delwin mywin
    view
}

monitorwindowsize ()
{
    currentLines=$LINES
    currentColumns=$COLUMNS
    while true; do
      if (( currentLines != LINES || currentColumns != COLUMNS )); then
        currentLines=$LINES
        currentColumns=$COLUMNS
        kill -SIGUSR1 $1
      fi
      sleep 0.1
    done
}

TRAPUSR1() {
    resetview
}

TRAPINT() {
    for jobs in $jobstates ; do
      jobid=${${jobs##*:*:}%=*}
      kill ${${jobs##*:*:}%=*}
    done
    zcurses end
    exit
}

zcurses init
loop $$
for jobs in $jobstates ; do
  jobid=${${jobs##*:*:}%=*}
  kill ${${jobs##*:*:}%=*}
done
zcurses end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found a way to make the SIGWINCH trap work. Tested with `zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)` (with ssh) and `zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)`:

```
zmodload zsh/curses

loop ()
{
    view
    while true; do
        unset raw
        unset key
        zcurses timeout mywin 50
        zcurses input mywin raw key
        now=$(date)
    done
}

view ()
{
    zcurses addwin mywin $(( LINES-4 )) $(( COLUMNS-4 )) 2 2 
    zcurses clear mywin
    zcurses border mywin
    zcurses refresh mywin
    zcurses move mywin $(( (LINES-4)/2 )) $(( (COLUMNS-8)/2 ))
    zcurses string mywin "Box"
    zcurses refresh mywin
}

resetview ()
{
    zcurses end
    tput clear
    zcurses clear mywin
    zcurses refresh mywin
    zcurses delwin mywin
    view
}

TRAPWINCH() {
    resetview
}

TRAPINT() {
    zcurses end
    exit
}
echoti civis
zcurses init
loop
zcurses end
```

[image]

I now use `zcurses input` instead of `read`. But the strange thing is that it also depends on `now=$(date)` (maybe another command works too). If `now=$(date)` is missing, the SIGWINCH trap will not work and the window will not be redrawn.

So if `now=$(date)` is missing, it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use `zselect`.  From the `zshmodules` [man page](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fzselect-Module):

> It is possible to call `zselect` with no file descriptors and a non-zero
> timeout for use as a finer-grained replacement for ‘sleep’; note,
> however, the return status is always 1 for a timeout.

The call to `zselect` here does appear to sleep for half a second:

```
> zmodload zsh/zselect
> type zselect
zselect is a shell builtin
> zselect -t 50
>
```

Comment: I have already tried that. But in this case it does not work. The reason could be that there is already a "read call" at the same time in another place in this script. You can also reproduce it if you replace `sleep 0.1` with `zselect -t 10` and run the script.